# How to structure an API consumer in PHP

Tags: php, api, design-patterns

This is a design question. I need some suggestion on how to structure a PHP module to consume an API service, with this features:

- The API has 2 separate hosts for 2 different versions (V1 and V2)
- the 2 APIs uses different endpoints, they can accept different parameters
- the 2 APIs returns the same data in JSON but structured differently

what I thought I could do is:

- a base abstract class called Client that load parameters and uses Guzzle to perform the call
- a ClientV2 class that extends Client, with methods like getServices, addService, ect...
- a ClientV1 class similar to ClientV2, V1 is going to be deprecated so I just need a few methods here

the idea would be to make this flexible enough if I will need to work on V3.

and how to manage the fact the the different APIs return different data?
I know how to implement guzzle. What I am looking for is a design pattern to structure this and an understanding on what classes I am going to need.

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is textbook definition of [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Extending your Client class here would not be ideal.

Ideally you'd never want your client to know about how data is composed. Ever. A client is a client and should do client things. Like calling an endpoint or send out some post data.

A client should be able to make calls regardless of the domain. It should return data or send data, without modifying it any way.

Quite frankly you can use Guzzle directly, but I can understand the need for wrapping it up in something to make future calls easier.

---

Next you have the core of the problem. The API versions themselvs.

Since you said data is structured differently you'll want a simple way to structure said data regardless of the API version. You'll still keep the API versions different for the sake of sense.

So what I propose is a some sort of normalizer intermediate class that can be injected into the API class that will deal with all that.

Enough talk, code is better.

---

```
class Client extends Guzzzle
{
    // methods here
}

abstract class AbstractAPI implements ApiInterface
{

    private $client;

    public function __construct(ClientInterface $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }
}


class APIv1 extends AbstractAPI
{
    private $normalizer;

    public function __construct(ClientInterface $client, NormalizerInterface $normalizer)
    {
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
        parent::__construct($client);
    }
}


class APIv2 extends AbstractAPI
{
    private $normalizer;

    public function __construct(ClientInterface $client, NormalizerInterface $normalizer)
    {
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
        parent::__construct($client);
    }
}

class Normalizer implements NormalizerInterface
{
    // normalize stuff depending on what API version you're using
}
```

In the code above you can see that no class is dependent on a concrete implementation.

And each class does one thing and it does it well.

The API classes can each handle a different version of the API and when the API version changes you can simply write a new class that handles that without modifying the existing implementation of a prior version, thus maintaining backwards compatibility with minimal effort.

Given that the new version will extra features, those can exist in the newly create API class.

The most important class here is the Normalizer. It will decide how the data is structured depending on what API version/class you're using, thus maintaining a single responsibility. The normalizer itself can decide how the data looks.

---

A concrete example

```
class Controller
{
    public function someAction()
    {
        $apiv1 = new APIv1();

        // we can assume that the data here is an array
        $data = $apiv1->getClient()->get('some/url', ['some_params']);

        // in between this you can do some other magic on the data that the normalizer shouldn't do
        // like add extra data or remove some, sort it, etc etc

        // Here you can return the normalized data for api_v1
        // how you do that it's up to you
        return $apiv1->normalize($data);

    }
}
```

Of course, everything I wrote here is a highlevel view of what *I* think you should do. It's not written in stone.

Adapt to your own needs and time constraints.